# How to take sum and average of indexed values in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

List B is expanded at index positions where list A has adjacent matching values using [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
A = [476, 1440, 3060, 3060, 500,500]
B = [0,4,10,15]
```

so resultant list is:

```
B_update1 = [0,4,10,10,15,15]
```

which after some intermediate steps will be:

```
B_update2 = [0,4,12,10,20,20]
```

Now I want to take sum and mean of duplicated values which will give me back:

```
B_mean = [0,4,11,20]
B_sum = [0,4,22,40]
```

I am not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Won't the mean of duplicate values always be the original value? Will they stay the same in the original list but be altered in the new list? Please explain.

Comment: Can you show how you create `B_updated` from `A` and `B`?

Comment: its from [following post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277068/how-to-duplicate-list-values-using-matching-value-index-from-another-list?noredirect=1#comment32060767_21277068) at SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B_update1, B_update2, B_mean, B_sum = [0,4,10,10,15,15], [0,4,12,10,20,20], [],[]
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
for num, grp in groupby(enumerate(B_update1), itemgetter(1)):
    tmp_list = [B_update2[idx] for idx, _ in grp]
    B_mean.append(sum(tmp_list)/len(tmp_list))
    B_sum.append(sum(tmp_list))
print B_mean, B_sum
```

**Output**

```
[0, 4, 11, 20] [0, 4, 22, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

The information you essentially need is the number of repetitions:

```
>>> A = [476, 1440, 3060, 3060, 500, 500]
>>> B = [0, 4, 10, 15]
>>> repetitions = [len(list(g)) for n, g in groupby(A)]
>>> repetitions
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

From this, you can construct both the `B_update1` and return back to the simple list:

```
>>> B_update1 = []
>>> for i, r in enumerate(repetitions):
        B_update1.extend([B[i]] * r)
>>> B_update1
[0, 4, 10, 10, 15, 15]

>>> B_update2 = [0, 4, 12, 10, 20, 20] # MAGIC

>>> B_sum, B_mean = [], []
>>> i = 0
>>> for r in repetitions:
        s = sum(B_update2[i:i + r])
        B_sum.append(s)
        B_mean.append(s / r)
        i += r

>>> B_sum
[0, 4, 22, 40]
>>> B_mean
[0.0, 4.0, 11.0, 20.0]
```